# Perl custom syntax for passing function arguments

Tags: perl, parsing, lexical

I have been using perl for some time now.
I want to know how I can run the following operation in perl:

```
subtract(40)(20)
```

To get the result:

```
20
```

I think I would have to look at custom parsing techniques for Perl.
This is what I am looking at right now:

[Devel::Declare](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eether/Devel-Declare-0.006014/lib/Devel/Declare.pm)

[Devel::CallParser](http://search.cpan.org/%7Ezefram/Devel-CallParser-0.001/lib/Devel/CallParser.pm)

and
http://www.perl.com/pub/2012/10/an-overview-of-lexing-and-parsing.html

Now, I am not sure what to look for or what to do.
Any help on HOW to go about this, WHAT to read would be appreciated. Please be clear.
Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to do? That *looks* as if you're trying to use a [function pointer](http://mpechner.wordpress.com/2008/04/11/perl-tutorial-function-pointers/).

Comment: I want to be able to run a subroutine called "subtract" in the manner described above.

Comment: `subtract(40)->(20)` would be valid syntax. If `subtract` returns a closure, it'll even work. `(40)(20)` isn't going to be valid unless you've done serious violence to the parser. And neither alternative is a more readable subtraction operator than the good old infix `-` we've all known since approximately kindergarten. Is there a point?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend trying [Parse::Keyword](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse%3a%3aKeyword). Parse::Keyword is really great for parsing custom syntax, as it lets you call back various parts of the Perl parser, such as `parse_listexpr`, `parse_block`, `parse_fullstmt`, etc (see [perlapi](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlapi)).

It has a drawback in that if you use those to parse expressions that close over variables, these are handled badly, but this can be worked around with [PadWalker](https://metacpan.org/pod/PadWalker).

Parse::Keyword (including PadWalker trickery) is what [Kavorka](https://metacpan.org/release/Kavorka) uses; and that does some pretty complex stuff! Early versions of p5-mop-redux used it too.

Anyway, here's a demonstration of how your weird function could be parsed...

```
use v5.14;
use strict;
use warnings;

# This is the package where we define the functions...
BEGIN {
  package Math::Weird;

  # Set up parsing for the functions
  use Parse::Keyword {
    add      => \&_parser,
    subtract => \&_parser,
    multiply => \&_parser,
    divide   => \&_parser,
  };

  # This package is an exporter of course
  use parent 'Exporter::Tiny';
  our @EXPORT = qw( add subtract multiply divide );

  # We'll need these things from PadWalker
  use PadWalker qw( closed_over set_closed_over peek_my );

  sub add {
    my @numbers = _grab_args(@_);
    my $sum = 0;
    $sum += $_ for @numbers;
    return $sum;
  }

  sub subtract {
    my @numbers = _grab_args(@_);
    my $diff = shift @numbers;
    $diff -= $_ for @numbers;
    return $diff;
  }

  sub multiply {
    my @numbers = _grab_args(@_);
    my $product = 1;
    $product *= $_ for @numbers;
    return $product;
  }

  sub divide {
    my @numbers = _grab_args(@_);
    my $quotient = shift @numbers;
    $quotient /= $_ for @numbers;
    return $quotient;
  }

  sub _parser {
    lex_read_space;

    my @args;
    while (lex_peek eq '(')
    {
      # read "("
      lex_read(1);
      lex_read_space;

      # read a term within the parentheses
      push @args, parse_termexpr;
      lex_read_space;

      # read ")"
      lex_peek eq ')' or die;
      lex_read(1);
      lex_read_space;
    }

    return sub { @args };
  }

  # In an ideal world _grab_args would be implemented like
  # this:
  #
  #    sub _grab_args { map scalar(&$_), @_ }
  #
  # But because of issues with Parse::Keyword, we need
  # something slightly more complex...
  #
  sub _grab_args {
    my $caller_vars = peek_my(2);
    map {
      my $code = $_;
      my $closed_over = closed_over($code);
      $closed_over->{$_} = $caller_vars->{$_} for keys %$closed_over;
      set_closed_over($code, $closed_over);
      scalar $code->();
    } @_;
  }

  # We've defined a package inline. Mark it as loaded, so
  # that we can `use` it below.
  $INC{'Math/Weird.pm'}  = __FILE__;
};

use Math::Weird qw( add subtract multiply );

say add(2)(3);          # says 5
say subtract(40)(20);   # says 20

say multiply( add(2)(3) )( subtract(40)(20) );   # says 100
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can live with the additions of a sigil and an arrow, you could [curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) `subtract` as in

```
my $subtract = sub {
  my($x) = @_;

  sub { my($y) = @_; $x - $y };
};
```

Call it as in

```
my $result = $subtract->(40)(20);
```

If the arrow is acceptable but not the sigil, recast `subtract` as

```
sub subtract {
  my($x) = @_;

  sub { my($y) = @_; $x - $y };
};
```

Invocation in this case looks like

```
my $result = subtract(40)->(20);
```

Comment: That's interesting how you don't need a `->` between the `(40)` and the `(20)` iff you have one to the left of the `(40)`. The scary kind of interesting...

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley In the “Using References” section of [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References), we read, “The arrow is optional *between* brackets subscripts …”

Comment: Hmm... in my part of the world (also the part of the world where perl and its documentation come from), "brackets" doesn't mean "parentheses". But I see the example also includes braces, which I don't consider to be brackets either. But `$array[$x]{foo}[0]` is valid with no arrows in it anywhere, while `subtract(40)(20)` rqeuires at least one arrow *somewhere*. It still seems to me that the "optional arrow" rule is applying differently to function-call parentheses than it does to array-lookup brackets or hash-lookup braces.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I require the call to be strictly like this: subtract(40)(20)
The prefix or suffix don't matter. I can violate the parser as much as I want.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't tack on broken syntax extensions on your program to solve a solved problem.
What you want are *closures*, and a technique sometimes called *currying*.

Currying is the job of transforming a function that takes multiple arguments into a function that is invoked multiple times with one argument each. For example, consider

```
sub subtract {
  my ($x, $y) = @_;
  return $x - $y;
}
```

Now we can create a subroutine that already provides the first argument:

```
sub subtract1 { subtract(40, @_) }
```

Invoking `subtract1(20)` now evaluates to `20`.

We can use *anonymous subroutines* instead, which makes this more flexible:

```
my $subtract = sub { subtract(40, @_) };
$subtract->(20);
```

We don't need that variable:

```
sub { subtract(40, @_) }->(20); # equivalent to subtract(40, 20)
```

We can write `subtract` in a way that does this directly:

```
sub subtract_curried {
  my $x = shift;
  # don't return the result, but a subroutine that calculates the result
  return sub {
    my $y = shift;
    return $x - $y;
  };
}
```

Now: `subtract_curried(40)->(20)` – notice the arrow in between, as we are dealing with a *code reference* (another name for anonymous subroutine, or closures).

This style of writing functions is much more common in functional languages like *Haskell* or *OCaml* where the syntax for this is prettier. It allows very flexible combinations of functions. If you are interested in this kind of programming in Perl, you might want to read [*Higher-Order Perl*](http://hop.perl.plover.com/).

Comment: I require the call to be strictly like this: subtract(40)(20)
My gratitude for your response.

Comment: @Heartache What problem are you actually trying to solve when you have such a strict requirement? If you really, really have to write a syntax extension, at least use `Parse::Keywords` and not one of the older (more broken) experiments.

Comment: It's a challenge problem.

Comment: Actually it is just that or if i can find an alternative :D The challenge is right there in my question.

Comment: @Heartache `my $source_code = "subtract(40)(20)"; die if $source_code ne "subtract(40)(20)"; $result = 20` – that wold be a solution I might be comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

@Heartache: Please forget this challenge as it makes no sense for the parser and the user.

You can think of using `fn[x][y]` or `fn{x}{y}` which are valid syntax variants - i.e. you can stack `[]` and `{}` but not lists, 
or `fn(x,y)` or `fn(x)->(y)` which do look nice, are also valid and meaningful syntax variants.
But `fn(x)(y)` will not know in which context the second list should be used.

For `fn(x)(y)` the common interpretation would be `fn(x); (y) => (y)`. It returns the 2nd list after evaluating the first call.

Answer (score -1):

You may create the [source code filter](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfilter):

```
package BracketFilter;

use Filter::Util::Call;

sub import {
    filter_add(sub {
        my $status;
        s/\)\(/, /g if ($status = filter_read()) > 0;
        return $status ;
    });
}

1;
```

And use it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use BracketFilter;

subtract(40)(20);

sub subtract {
    return $_[0] - $_[1];
}
```

Comment: Source filters are a bug. Do not use them to implement syntax extensions – most of the time, `Parse::Keyword` is a better solution.

Comment: @amon, see [`Parse::Keyword`](http://metacpan.org/pod/release/DOY/Parse-Keyword-0.08/lib/Parse/Keyword.pm): _DEPRECATED: write syntax extensions in perl. DO NOT USE!_

Comment: All syntax extension modules are broken to some degree – [tobyink's answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20669696/1521179) shows how to overcome the Parse::Keyword limitations. This module still is the next best thing to directly using [Perl's C API](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html).

Comment: @amon, and source filters are the core part of the Perl distribution.

Comment: @amon, `Parse::Keyword` used API features that introduced in Perl 5.14. What about older versions?

Comment: This is a matter of assessing which approach is less wrong. The issue with source filters is that they don't compose, can easily get confused, and would need to parse Perl, which is famously Turing-complete. Parse::Keyword has some notable issues with closures, but has none of the downsides of source filters. `Filter` is in Core because it's required to parse source files with exotic encodings, not because it's the recommended way to extend syntax.

Comment: @amon I didn't say that `Filter` is the recommended way. But it's the possible and not the wrong way for solve this problem.